# not able to resolve LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
l1=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1], [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]]
l2=[0] *500
```

and I am trying to solve this as a linear equation as follows:

```
a = np.array(l1)
b = np.array(l2)
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
x
```

But I keep getting an error:LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909600/linalgerror-last-2-dimensions-of-the-array-must-be-square)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909600/linalgerror-last-2-dimensions-of-the-array-must-be-square

Comment: A simple search for "Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square", either here or on g..gle should help.

Comment: The solution in the link explains the reason but,  I have been specifically asked to use just linealg.solve() . I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what changes do I make to the code.